# Definition of complete in the context of Lebesgue measurable sets

Tags: measure-theory, definition

I came across this statement on Lebesgue measurable sets.

> The Lebesgue measurable sets are said to be complete because every subset of a null set is again measurable and the lebesgue measurable sets are a completion of the Borel sets.

What does complete and completion mean in this context?

Any help with this doubt is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A measure $\mu$ defined on a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal F$ of subsets of a set $X$ is *complete* if and only if any subset of a set of measure $0$ is measurable, that is, it belongs to $\mathcal F$ (and has measure $0$). For example, the Borel sets of reals with the standard measure do not form a complete measure because one can show that there are only $\mathfrak c$ many Borel sets, but the Cantor set has measure $0$ and $2^{\mathfrak c}>\mathfrak c$ subsets, so some of them are not measurable.

Any measure admits a completion. The *completion* of the measure $\mu$ (defined on $\mathcal F$) is defined by considering the smallest $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal G$ of subsets of $X$ that contains all subsets of any $Y\in\mathcal F$ of measure $0$. For example, Lebesgue measure is obtained that way starting with the Borel sets. It turns out a set $A$ is in $\mathcal G$ iff there are some $B,C\in\mathcal F$ and a set $D\subset C$ with $\mu(C)=0$ and $A=B\cup D$.

For Lebesgue measure one can show that a set $A$ is measurable iff there is some Borel set $B$ such that the symmetric difference $A\triangle B=(A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A)$ is contained in some Borel set of measure $0$.

One can check that the measure $\mu$ admits a unique extension to $\mathcal G$, that is, there is a unique measure $\hat\mu$ defined on $\mathcal G$ with the property that $\hat\mu(B)=\mu(B)$ for all $B\in\mathcal F$. With $A,B,C,D$ as above, we have that $\hat\mu(A)=\mu(B)$. Of course, one cannot quite *define* $\hat\mu$ this way, without first checking that this definition makes sense, that is, if $E,F\in\mathcal F$, and  $\mu(F)=0$, $G\subset F$, and also $A=E\cup G$, then we have $\mu(B)=\mu(E)$. This measure $\hat\mu$ is complete in the sense of the first paragraph.

The Wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_measure) has a few more details.

Comment: How does one show that there are only $\mathfrak c$ many Borel sets

Comment: Any argument uses a modicum of set theory. Briefly, one can associate to each Borel set a countable "code" that describes how the set is made up from basic open sets by taking countable unions and complements. There are only countably many basic open sets (rational intervals), and the code is countable, so this gives us at most $\mathfrak c$ many sets. To formalize this, we present each code as a tree of height a countable ordinal (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28set_theory%29).

Comment: Another approach is to decompose the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal B$ of Borel sets as $\bigcup_{\alpha<\omega_1}\mathcal B_\alpha$, where $\omega_1$ is the first uncountable ordinal, $\mathcal B_0$ consists of basic open sets, $\mathcal B_\lambda$ is the union of the previous $\mathcal B_\tau$ for $\lambda$ limit, and $\mathcal B_{\alpha+1}$ consists of complements and countable unions of sets in $\mathcal B_\alpha$. One checks by transfinite induction that each $\mathcal B_\alpha$ has size at most $\mathfrak c$, and therefore so does the union.

Answer (score 1):

A $\sigma$-algebra is complete with respect to a measure $\mu$ if every subset of a set of $\mu$-measure zero is measurable.   The completion of a $\sigma$-algebra with respect to the measure $\mu$ is just the $\sigma$-algebra generated by throwing in all of the subsets of $\mu$-measure zero.